# Putting function definition after call in R knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Quick, and probably stupid, question: in a R markdown/knitr document, is it possible to put a function definition at the end of the doc (e.g. in an Appendix) after the function is actually called?

Comment: You can define the function at the beginning and hide it. Then, print the definition in the appendix.

Comment: `body(function_name)` shows the function definition

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it possible to put a function definition at the end of the document, after the function is actually called?

Technically, no. A function needs to be *defined* before it is called. However, as the question relates to `knitr` it should be rephrased:

> Is it possible to *show* a function definition at the end of the document, after the function is actually called?

Yes, and there are several ways to achieve this. Note that options 2 and 3 can be found in [Print highlighted source code of a function](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pretty/).

### Option 1: Reuse chunks

Define the function *before* it is used.

````
```{r definition, echo = FALSE}
myfun <- function(x) {
  return(sprintf("You passed me %s", x))
}
```

Use the function:
```{r}
myfun(123)
```

Show the chunk where it was defined:
```{r definition, eval = FALSE}
```
````

An empty chunk with the same label as another non-empty chunk "inherits" the latter's code. This is described in [How to reuse chunks](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/). 
The code inside the chunk `definition` is hidden at first (`echo = FALSE`). Later, when the code is to be printed, use `eval = FALSE` in order to avoid evaluating the code again.

This option is handy when the function is defined in a separate chunk.

### Option 2: Simple `print`

This is the simplest option but the output won't have syntax highlighting. Just define the function in a hidden chunk, use it and print the function definition later:

````
Define the function *before* it is used.

```{r definition, echo = FALSE}
myfun <- function(x) {
  return(sprintf("You passed me %s", x))
}
```

Use the function:
  ```{r}
myfun(123)
```


```{r}
myfun
```
````

### Option 3: Generate a chunk containing the function definition

This option is described on [Yihui's website](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pretty/). It uses the function `insert_fun` to generate a chunk that contains the function definition.

```
insert_fun = function(name) {
  read_chunk(lines = capture.output(dump(name, '')), labels = paste(name, 'source', sep = '-'))
}
```

This approach is very flexible because it doesn't matter if the function is defined in a separate chunk or in a file that is `source`d.

`insert_fun` takes the name of an function (as `character`) and creates a chunk labelled `functionname-source`:

````
Define the function *before* it is used.

```{r definition, echo = FALSE}

# Define your function. 
myfun <- function(x) { 
  return(sprintf("You passed me %s", x))
}

library(knitr)

# Define insert_fun.
insert_fun = function(name) {
  read_chunk(lines = capture.output(dump(name, '')), labels = paste(name, 'source', sep = '-'))
}

insert_fun("myfun") # creates a chunk labelled "myfun-source"
```

Use the function:
  ```{r}
myfun(123)
```


```{r myfun-source, eval = FALSE}
```
````

Comment: hi there, just getting started with knitr; at the moment I am defining a function in a chunk and then reusing it 4 or 5 times to make a knitr pdf. Can i call the function from it's own script instead of defining it in the doc? is this what you allude to with option 3?

Comment: @Sam If you don't want to have the definition of the function in the main document, you can use [code externalization](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/) or simply define the function in a separate R script and `source` that script (although this may defeat reproducibility). Option 3 in my answer above is about how to *show* a function that has been defined somewhere else.

Comment: @ CL. ah yes i understand what you're saying in option 3 now, and how it ties to pretty printing etc. I am happy enough for some functions to be sourced and some to be defined in document. I will experiment, thanks